# Openshift/kubernetes: map serviceaccount secret to an environment variable

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

Is there a way to populate the serviceaccount secrets content to an environment variable?

Example: when a pod is started, it contains a `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/secrets/serviceaccount/` folder that contains `token`, `ca.crt`... and other that is the result to map the `serviceaccount` sercret to a folder.

Is there anyway to map `serviceaccountsecret.token` to an environment variable?

**EDIT**

I'm deploying kubernetes/openshift objects using fabric8 maven plugin. Nevertheless, I was looking for a way of setting this information up on PodSpec.

So, currently openshift/kubernetes is mapping service account information located into secrets and then it's automatically mapped to filesystem (`/var/run...).

I'm looking for a way to map this "unknown" service account secret to environment variable (I mean, I don't know which is the name of this secret, when I'm creating PodSpec).

```
$ oc get secrets
NAME                       TYPE                                  DATA      AGE
builder-dockercfg-hplx4    kubernetes.io/dockercfg               1         43m
builder-token-bkd8h        kubernetes.io/service-account-token   4         43m
builder-token-gpckp        kubernetes.io/service-account-token   4         43m
default-dockercfg-q2vpx    kubernetes.io/dockercfg               1         43m
default-token-hpr7l        kubernetes.io/service-account-token   4         43m
default-token-r5225        kubernetes.io/service-account-token   4         43m
deployer-dockercfg-6h7nw   kubernetes.io/dockercfg               1         43m
deployer-token-svmvf       kubernetes.io/service-account-token   4         43m
deployer-token-tmg9x       kubernetes.io/service-account-token   4         43m
vault-cert                 kubernetes.io/tls                     2         42m
```

As you can see, openshiftshift/kubernetes creates secrets regarding with each service account:

```
$ oc get sa
NAME       SECRETS   AGE
builder    2         44m
default    2         44m
deployer   2         44m
```

Each secret has a form like:

```
$ oc describe secret default-token-hpr7l
Name:         default-token-hpr7l
Namespace:    ra-sec
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  kubernetes.io/created-by=openshift.io/create-dockercfg-secrets
              kubernetes.io/service-account.name=default
              kubernetes.io/service-account.uid=82ae89d7-898a-11e8-8d35-f28ae3e0478e

Type:  kubernetes.io/service-account-token

Data
====
ca.crt:          1070 bytes
namespace:       6 bytes
service-ca.crt:  2186 bytes
token:           eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJrdWJlcm5ldGVzL3NlcnZpY2VhY2NvdW50Iiwia3ViZXJuZXRlcy5pby9zZXJ2aWNlYWNjb3VudC9uYW1lc3BhY2UiOiJyYS1zZWMiLCJrdWJlcm5ldGVzLmlvL3Nl...
```

Each secret is mapped to filesystem automatically. Nevertheless, I'd like to write into PodSpec:

```
env:
- name: KUBERNETES_TOKEN
  valueFrom:
    secretKeyRef:
      name: <unknown service account secret name>
      key: token
```

I hope I've explianed a bit better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a secret annotated with `kubernetes.io/service-account.name` annotation.

This annotation provides related service account information to current secret.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: vault-auth-secret
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/service-account.name: vault-auth
type: kubernetes.io/service-account-token
```

By this way, you are able to create a named secret with desired data.

```
- name: KUBERNETES_TOKEN
  valueFrom:
    secretKeyRef:
      name: vault-auth-secret
      key: token
```

Comment: Docs for the env `valueFrom` part: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-environment-variables

Answer (score 0):

How are you deploying your application, S2I?

If yes, you can use a custom `.s2i/bin/run` script to set it yourself from the contents of the file and then run the original S2I `run` script.

See the chapter 'Customizing Source-to-Image Builds' in the free eBook:

- https://www.openshift.com/deploying-to-openshift/

for more details.

Comment: I've added some details into post.

Comment: So you want the name of the secret to somehow be populated automatically, rather than having to enter it manual into the deployment config?

Comment: Entering it in manually is only way I can see you can do it if you want to inject it via a environment variable defined in the deployment config. How you work out the token isn't that hard. Use ``oc describe sa`` as explained in http://cookbook.openshift.org/accessing-an-openshift-cluster/how-can-i-create-a-service-account-for-scripted-access.html

Comment: To have it done automatically, only way I know could do it, is to override the S2I run script in the image.